# Microsoft Edge animation issue

Tags: css

Just curious why this doesn't work in Edge. It works in all other browsers I have checked this out in. Is there a bug in Edge that is causing this?

Fyi it's not my code, just curious.

```
/**
 *  Animations
 */
@keyframes checkboxCheckedAnimation {
  50%, 100% {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
  }
  100% {
border-radius: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes checkboxUncheckedAnimation {
  0% {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
  }
}

@keyframes changeWidthOfElementAnimation {
  50% {
width: 0;
  }
  100% {
width: 100%;
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/WispProxy/details/GqzoYg

Comment: might have to use vendor-prefixes

Comment: I have tried vendor prefixes, they seem to have no effect.

Comment: the last keyframe works in Edge without vendor-prefixes. What code have you tried? https://jsfiddle.net/7b6errxo/

Comment: All the code can be found at the codepen link.

Comment: I have narrowed the issue down to the keyframe checkboxCheckedAnimation, not sure why it works in other browsers and not in Edge though. https://jsfiddle.net/oq4aqjsL/1/

Comment: @Josan Iracheta: Microsoft Edge doesn't use prefixes for animations. Not even IE does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this worked, but this did the trick.

```
   @keyframes checkboxCheckedAnimation {
  50% {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
  }
  100% {
border-radius: 0;
// Added these lines
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

Comment: On the surface it looks like Microsoft Edge is incorrectly erasing the width and height declarations when cascading the two 100% keyframes rules. That shouldn't be happening, as you might expect from any other CSS rule.